# Telerik MVC grid timezone issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, telerik, timezone, telerik-grid

I'm working with a legacy code, a MVC 3 using telerik UI old version (no kendo), so was neccesary glabalize it about the dateformats and currencies, and setting the currentCulture with the wish culture it works, but when I did the deployment on the web server I noticed how the Grids datetime columns recalculate the time according to the client timezone, and that's incorrect, because on the same webserver run multiple deployments of that application and the clients can be diferent countries, then I'm facing a big trouble. The telerik documentation doesn't talk about "auto convert dates according the client-side timezone settings" and these components sometimes are deprecated.

I have this code in the _Layout.cshtml

```
Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
    .OnDocumentReady(@<text></text>) 
    .Globalization(true))
```

This is my grid, and it has 2 datetime columns, both are recalculated
when the grid renders, I don't know how avoid that, Other way could be using a get property on the model which return the date like string, but that workarround I would spend more time because there are several grids on the application.

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Models.AppointmentModels>(_AppointmentList).Name("Appointment").DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.AppointmentID)).DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
.Select("GetCRMAppointments", "Opportunity")
.Update("UpdateCRMAppointments", "Opportunity")
.Delete("DeleteCRMAppointments", "Opportunity"))
.Columns(columns =>
          {

               columns.Bound(o => o.StartTime).Title("start date").Width(140);
               columns.Bound(o => o.EndTime).Title("End Date").Width(140);

          })
```

Comment: I had a similar problem on an Asp.net website. I ended up using a class to convert the date time as needed in each website.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue too.  I was only interested in the time portion of the DateTime values.  I resolved it by adding formatted string values to my model and using that as a ClientTemplate in the View.

Model Code:

```
[DisplayName("Start Time")]
[UIHint("Time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
//Formatted string below.  Your formatting may vary
public string StartTimeString { get { return StartTime.ToString("t"); } }
```

Column Binding in the View:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.StartTime).ClientTemplate("<#= StartTimeString #>").Width(50).ReadOnly();
```